# shell linux unix xargs -i replace string

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, xargs

I have hard time understanding the xargs part of this command :

```
find -type f | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs -ifil file fil | \
   grep ELF | grep executable | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -ifil find fil -exec chmod 744 {} \;
```

What I have understood: looking for file not directory, then replacing "  " by "\ ", then give the output to xargs that will pass it to the command file? why using the `-i` to replace? Then grep ELF and executable, take the first column by using `:` delimeter, do again an xargs with the same options to chmod 744 ?

Comment: IMHO it's such an ill-conceived command I'm not sure you will learn much from trying to pick it apart - it could be done better with a single `find -exec` and proper shell quoting

Comment: Yes, but the "xargs -ifil file fil" part, i do not understand this part.. for the rest i can get my head around it.

Comment: Well `fil` is just the author's choice for the `replace-str` - a more commonly used string is `{}` so for example you will often see `xargs -I {} somecommand {}` (the lower case `i` is also deprecated in favor of upper case `I`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `-istr` is a (deprecated) alternative for `-I str`, and the GNU man page tells what `-I` does:

```
-I replace-str
      Replace  occurrences  of  replace-str  in the initial-arguments with 
      names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not termi‐
      nate  input  items;  instead the separator is the newline character. 
      Implies -x and -L 1.
```

In other words, with `-ixxx` (or `-Ixxx`), `xargs` replaces the string `xxx` in the command given with the current item before running the command, and also makes `xargs` run the given command once for each input line, instead of the default where it stacks multiple items to a single command invocation, and considers whitespace-separated strings as distinct items.

E.g. here, the `echo` command runs twice, with `xxx` replaced by the contents of the two input lines as appropriate:

```
$ printf "foo bar\nqwerty\n" | xargs -ixxx echo ":xxx:xxx:"
:foo bar:foo bar:
:qwerty:qwerty:
```

Comment: Thank you the example made it clear , i have also changed my title for search purpose.